# Publish single file to AWS from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services

When using the One-Click Publish in Visual Studio, you can right click on a single file (like one html file) and publish it. Is there an equivalent feature when publishing to AWS, or do you have to publish the whole application every time?

Edit: I'm specifically interested in publishing to Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: Publish it to what AWS service? EC2? ECS? S3? Elastic Beanstalk? More details are needed in order to answer your question.

Comment: Elactic Beanstalk (I'll update the original question)